# How to create Java applets?

Tags: java, applet

I am just stepping into Java and need help with some basic things. I want to create an applet. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly - start with forgetting all about applets. Years ago, the applet was the warmup for Java tutorials, nowadays, you should start with 'applications' - classes that implement the main method.

Today people prefer Java Script or Java Web Start for web applications.

Comment: This does not really answer the question

Comment: Depends. Strictly seen - no it isn't. Johannes provided the best answer. But Bhuvana is starting to learn Java and my answer was my advice to not waste time with learning Java Applet technology. If he hadn't said, he was a beginner, I hadn't posted this text as an answer :)

Comment: Sometimes though, one has little choice in that. Some universities apparently *still* have applet homeworks. And well, apart from deriving from Applet there isn't too much difference between an applet and a normal application, except maybe that you have to pay less attention to a SecurityManager.

Comment: Cool - just got an uncommented downvote after **two years**. One should get a badge for this :D

Answer (score 9):

The [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/) are usually a good place to start.

Comment: googling instead of others - pricesless :) (+1)

Comment: okei actuall am jus fresher..nw workin as software trainee..wanna do smart card application in java..where to start?????

Comment: `s/?+/?/`. Also you may want to ask another question **and** put some more effort into actually writing questions people want to answer.

Answer (score 0):

java tutorial is a great place to start.

are you sure you want to start with applets? they are outdated. 
I'd suggest you start with java application. it's simpler to understand java that way and then you can "go web" in more modern ways.

Answer (score 0):

Why not download netbeans and take a look at the tutorials on www.netbeans.org.

Having the ide deal with build issues help you get to understand things quicker if your a newbie.